# Julia: How can I get the residuals of the regression using FixedEffectModels package

Tags: regression, julia

I am trying to find the residuals of the following regression but I couldn't find it.

```
Model=reg(Data,@model(Y~X,save = true))
```

In the documentation, it says the residuals will be saved in a data frame, but it's not the "Data"

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  It would help to know what those variables mean.

Comment: I changed the variables, just a simple regression using the FixedEffectModels Package.

Answer (score 0):

I got sth using this:
    residuals(Model,Data)

Comment: Nice!  Yeah I was trying to experiment with Julia a bit, but the package manager is very buggy, at least on Windows (64bit).  Hope they get it fixed.

Comment: The package manager seems orthogonal to this problem? Anyway, if you're running into problems, bug issues are much appreciated, or ask questions on discourse.julialang.org .